# Accessing further objects from the results of a loop in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't even know what to search for on this, so I'll just explain what I'm trying to do. On my user index page I'm printing out a list of the latest users with the immediate info (stuff from the users table). How do I go about pulling the latest post by that user, then? I don't know what to do in the controller that will enable me to have access to each result separately.

Here is a simplified view:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= link_to user.username, user_path(user) %><br />
  <%= user.email %>
  # this is where I would show the user's latest post
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
def index
    @users = User.order('created_at DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 24)
    @user_latest_post = ???
end
```

Comment: you can directly access users posts via `user.posts` and apply each on it

Comment: I do this in the view, yes? What if I just want the latest one?

Comment: you can create scope inside model like `scope :latest_posts, -> { order('created_at DESC').limit(10) }`

Comment: and use this in view with `user.posts.latest_posts`

Comment: Okay, last question, that scope would go inside the posts model, correct?

Comment: yes it will go inside post model

Comment: it will cause a N+1 problem, recommend to use association

Answer (score 1):

You should set up `User` so that it has an association with `Post`. This allows you to access all Posts belonging to that User (like `user.posts`). This isn't totally necessary for your question, but is probably something you want (or have already done).

Then you need to create a second, scoped association that gets the latest `Post`. This way you can use `includes` in your controller and avoid an N+1 issue (otherwise it will do a new query for the latest post every time you iterate through a user with that `each` block).

Lastly, you need to choose what you want to display about the Post. Convention would have you make a shared "partial" view for Post that you can reuse. This means you can just tell Rails to `render user.latest_post` and it will know what to do (assuming you've defined this partial).

I give code examples below to explain what I mean:

```rb
# models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  has_one :latest_post, class_name: "Post", -> { order(created_at: :desc).limit(1) }
end

# controllers/users_controller.rb
def index
    @users = User.includes(:latest_post).order(created_at: :desc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 24)
end

# views/users/index.erb
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= link_to user.username, user_path(user) %><br />
  <%= user.email %>
  <%= render user.latest_post %>
<% end %>

# views/posts/_post.erb
<%= post.text %> 
# or whatever you want here
```

Comment: Here I get a `NameError in Users#index` which is `undefined local variable or method 'latest_post'`. This is from `/app/views/posts/_post.html.erb where line #1`...

Comment: You need to make sure to use the correct variable name. It should be `post` not `latest_post` in that partial as that partial is called `_post.html.erb` not `_latest_post.html.erb`. The rails automagic assumes you want the local variable in that partial to be named after the model (`Post`).